# Does any body know how to dynamically change outline in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I know the setting <kbd>Edit > Preferences > General > **Check "Scale stroke & effects"**</kbd>.

But this setting is changing outline setting for all objects in illustrator. Does anybody know **setting for only selected objects**? I am CorelDraw user previously and this is very easy to do in CorelDraw.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can not.

Strokes either scale globally or not. There is no object-specific setting.

You need to toggle that preferences item if you want to change the behavior at any time.

The Scale Strokes item is also seen on the **Transform** panel - which may be easier to get to if you use it often.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Scott. There is no way to specify this on a per object basis.

There is, however, a workaround but you'd need to separate the stroke from the fill.

Try this:

[image: example]

You should then be able to scale the object as needed and what was a stroke (now a filled path) will scale.

Comment: Semantics, but once expanded, there is no longer a "stroke". Everything becomes a shape. So, stroke options will no longer be available for any existing strokes.

Comment: Yes, but as a shape, it will scale. Not saying it's the perfect solution but if you are set with the stroke you need and just need to scale it, this does the job.

Comment: Agreed :) As posted, it was mere semantics :)